# how to add each line richtextbox into array vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to Split the the text in the RichTextBox per line into array in vb.net
if i show array(0) it will show the first line of richtextbox, array(1) will show the second line and go on.

Im new in VB and I cant find any decent link or site. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Richtextbox has a property called `Lines` ([link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx). Which returns an `String()` where each line is a new entry in the Array. More info can be found in the link above.

Code example

```
Dim myArr As String() = MyRichTextBox.Lines
```

**Note:** Searching "Richtextbox to array" (in google) does supply you with plenty of helpful webpages